# Finding number of planes that can be formed from a given lattice

Tags: geometry

Given a $d$-dimensional cube with side length $s$, how many distinct planes can be drawn through this cube so that they intersect the unit spaces through the center?

I tried calculating it using: $$s^d\choose3$$But this calculation includes repeated instances. How do I find the number of distinct planes?

Comment: As written, the answer to this question is infinity.  I can draw a plane through the center of the cube at an arbitrary angle, and then again, and then again.  As long as I don't repeat an angle, I get another plane through the cube.  Could you perhaps ask the question in a different way?

Comment: @NicNic8 I meant so that it intersects the unit spaces through the center

Comment: I think the answer is d.  This would be the case with a 3 dimensional cube.  I don't see why s would be involved in the calculation at all.